# Enum frequencies - error UndefinedFunctionError

Tags: enums, elixir

I am trying to use `Enum` function `frequencies` but it isn't work. 
Base on documentation [Enum - Elixir v1.10.2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#frequencies/1)

When I try to use that example:

```
Enum.frequencies(~w{ant buffalo ant ant buffalo dingo})
# OR
Enum.frequencies(["ant", "buffalo", "ant", "ant", "buffalo", "dingo"])
```

I always revive error:

```
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Enum.frequencies/1 is undefined or private
```

I have already tried to execute that code example at iex shell, `.ex` file body and online [Repl](https://repl.it/languages/elixir).

My local elixir version `Elixir 1.9.4 (compiled with Erlang/OTP 22)`

It seems to me that I miss some essential point at documentation, so I am looking for some pro tip ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation what you provided is describes **Elixir v1.10.2** but you use [Elixir 1.9.4](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.9.4). Looks like the function `Enum.frequencies/1` is not exist in Elixir 1.9.4 at all and this function was added in version `1.10.0` and higher. By this reason you see error. I suppose, if you need to use `Enum.frequencies/1`, you need upgrade Elixir to latest version or at least until of version `1.10.0`.

Comment: Elixir version upgraded, now it works as expected. Thank you.
I misunderstood documentation annotation for `Enum.frequencies/1` - `since 1.10.0`  as `since 1.1.0`